# transition not working in chrome

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/x3Kc7/1/

```
.play {
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    transition: all .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;

}

.play:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

This code works perfectly in firefox, however not in chrome. What is incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `-webkit` vendor for the transform property: `-webkit-transform: scale(1.2)`, as it isn't supported in Chrome otherwise. [**Same goes for other**](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d) `-webkit` browsers like Safari.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/x3Kc7/2/) - works in Chrome.

```
.play:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Aside from that, you would also need:

`-moz-transform: scale(1.2)` if you want support in FF 16<

`-ms-transform: scale(1.2)` if you want support in IE9

`-o-transform: scale(1.2)` if you want support in Opera 12<

It will otherwise work in all major browsers.

Comment: I thought that prefix-webkit was not necessary in the latest versions of Chrome. thanks

Comment: @user455318 You're welcome. according to **[this](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d)** it isn't.. looks like FF was faster :p

Comment: @JoshPowell 1+ To yours too. Essentially the same thing, just less than a minute slower :p

Comment: @JoshC I believe an entire 40 seconds slower :p

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include the `-webkit-` prefix for your hover animation.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/x3Kc7/3/)

What I changed,

```
.play:hover {
   transform: scale(1.2);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
   -o-transform: scale(1.2);
}
```